# Want to use Google map api on localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have faced an issue with my Google Map API while getting nearest places.

Code:

```
var headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url:    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyCLf2OhSgKKOju1hpUBirFtZ-W26zObyVI?sensor=false',
    headers: headers
}

$http(req).success(function(d) {
    alert(d)
});
```

Error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8…=food&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyCLf2OhSgKKOju1hpUBirFtZ-W26zObyVI?sensor=false.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: The places-webservice is not intended to be used via ajax, use the methods of the [places-library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) for clientside requests.

Comment: My need only to get nearest places, therefore I'm using the api. It's work fine with postman but not work with localhost:8100.

Answer (score -2):

```
var headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

var req = {
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyCLf2OhSgKKOju1hpUBirFtZ-W26zObyVI?sensor=false',
    headers:headers
}
$http.get(req.url,header).success(function(d){
    alert(d)
});
```